# PHP web development on NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans, ide

Whats tools/features do you use in NetBeans for PHP Web Development?

In other word, how does NetBeans benefit you for PHP Web development?

When I do web development on NetBean, the only thing that benefit list of php functions popup as soon I type and the custom function/method/classes/object names popup.

Comment: i am not sure there is a question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend:
http://netbeans.org/features/php/

Other then what you have mentioned, you can debug php which could be useful...

Oh, and mysql integration...

Answer (score 1):

You can [integrate PHPUnit](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/phpunit.html), [xDebug](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug), jenkins etc. There are also plugins for Smarty, Symfony, and Zend frameworks.

Answer (score -1):

Yes that is the idea of an IDE. it gives you help for typing out your functions and the like..